# Select one value from a group based on order from other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

## Problem

Suppose I have this table `tab` ([fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad3987/2) available).

```
| g | a | b |     v |
---------------------
| 1 | 3 | 5 |   foo |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |   bar |
| 1 | 2 | 9 |   baz |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |   dog |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |   cat |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | horse |
| 2 | 3 | 8 |   pig |
```

I'm grouping rows by `g`, and for each group I want one value from column `v`. However, I don't want *any* value, but I want the value from the row with maximal `a`, and from all of those, the one with maximal `b`. In other words, my result should be

```
| 1 |   bar |
| 2 | horse |
```

## Current solution

I know of a query to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT grps.g,
(SELECT v FROM tab
 WHERE g = grps.g
 ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC
 LIMIT 1) AS r
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT g FROM tab) grps
```

## Question

But I consider this query rather **ugly**. Mostly because it uses a **dependant subquery**, which feels like a real performance killer. So I wonder whether there is an easier solution to this problem.

## Expected answers

The most likely answer I expect to this question would be some kind of add-on or patch for MySQL (or MariaDB) which does provide a feature for this. But I'll welcome other useful inspirations as well. Anything which works without a dependent subquery would qualify as an answer.

If your solution only works for a single ordering column, i.e. couldn't distinguish between `cat` and `horse`, feel free to suggest that answer as well as I expect it to be still useful to the majority of use cases. For example, `100*a+b` would be a likely way to order the above data by both columns while still using only a single expression.

I have a few pretty hackish solutions in mind, and might add them after a while, but I'll first look and see whether some nice new ones pour in first.

---

## Benchmark results

As it is pretty hard to compare the various answers just by looking at them, I've run some benchmarks on them. This was run on my own desktop, using MySQL 5.1. The numbers won't compare to any other system, only to one another. You probably should be doing your own tests with your real-life data if performance is crucial to your application. When new answers come in, I might add them to my script, and re-run all the tests.

- 100,000 items, 1,000 groups to choose from, InnoDb:

  1. 0.166s for [MvG (from question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12726549)
  2. 0.520s for [RichardTheKiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728212)
  3. 2.199s for [xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726666)
  4. 19.24s for [Dems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727443) (sequential sub-queries)
  5. 48.72s for [acatt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726837)
- 100,000 items, 50,000 groups to choose from, InnoDb:

  1. 0.356s for [xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726666)
  2. 0.640s for [RichardTheKiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728212)
  3. 0.764s for [MvG (from question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12726549)
  4. 51.50s for [acatt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726837)
  5. *too long* for [Dems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727443) (sequential sub-queries)
- 100,000 items, 100 groups to choose from, InnoDb:

  1. 0.163s for [MvG (from question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12726549)
  2. 0.523s for [RichardTheKiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728212)
  3. 2.072s for [Dems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727443) (sequential sub-queries)
  4. 17.78s for [xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726666)
  5. 49.85s for [acatt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726837)

So it seems that my own solution so far isn't all that bad, even with the dependent subquery. Surprisingly, the solution by acatt, which uses a dependent subquery as well and which I therefore would have considered about the same, performs much worse. Probably something the MySQL optimizer can't cope with. The solution RichardTheKiwi proposed seems to have good overall performance as well. The other two solutions heavily depend on the structure of the data. With many groups small groups, xdazz' approach outperforms all other, whereas the solution by Dems performs best (though still not exceptionally good) for few large groups.

Comment: What index(es) did you apply to the table?  Also, note that RichardTheKiwi's approach appears to be quite stable.  I'd also estimate that it is linear as you scale the number of items in total.

Comment: @Dems, auto increment id as primary key which is not involved in the query, and `(g,a,b)` as a composite unique key. As sorting takes O(<i>n</i> log <i>n</i>) and I doubt that MySQL is clever enough to optimize the sorting to a selection, I estimate his solution to be slightly slower than linear, but the difference seems small. [Script available at dpaste](http://dpaste.com/hold/809915/) for a while.

Comment: cc @Dems // First rule of benchmarks is to state the margin of error. My solution should produce almost the same result for all 3, and the range is about right. Surprising the 2nd would blow out by that much. I can't be fussed right now, but would be interesting to see the EXPLAIN against all queries. Your query would be (n log n) and heavily dependent on group density leading using DISTINCT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT g, a, b, v
  FROM (
            SELECT *, 
                   @rn := IF(g = @g, @rn + 1, 1) rn, 
                   @g := g
              FROM (select @g := null, @rn := 0) x, 
                   tab
          ORDER BY g, a desc, b desc, v
       ) X
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Single pass. All the other solutions look O(n^2) to me.

Comment: This looks pretty good in terms of performance, as you employ an idea similar to what Dems writes about `ROW_NUMBER` in other RDBMS. What has me worried is that according to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html), *“The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined […]”* (please also read surrounding paragraph). As I see it, there is no guarantee that the rows will get numbered in the order specified by the `ORDER BY`. Is there?

Comment: Posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12728949) asking about guarantees for this kind of query.

Comment: I've accepted this answer. On the one hand it exhibits good behaviour over a wide range of my benchmarks. On the other hand it is code I wouldn't have used before asking this question, but I'd consider to use now, so I learned quite a lot from it. Even though I keep wondering about guarantees.

Answer (score 5):

This way doesn't use sub-query.

```
SELECT t1.g, t1.v
FROM tab t1
LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t1.g = t2.g AND (t1.a < t2.a OR (t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b < t2.b))
WHERE t2.g IS NULL
```

***Explanation:***

The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when t1.a is at its maximum value, there is no s2.a with a greater value and the s2 rows values will be NULL.

Comment: [Incorrect result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad3987/16): you don't even select the `v` value. Your query basically does `SELECT g, MAX(a) FROM tab GROUP BY g` only.

Comment: @MvG My typo, change `t1.a` to `t1.v` will give you the right result.

Comment: Still won't break the tie between cat and horse yet, but that can be fixed. Feel free to include the [fixed version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad3987/33) into your answer.

Comment: @MvG Yes, your fixed version is right, I didn't read all of your question.

Comment: `This way doesn't use sub-query.` and that's good? This is O(n^2) and not something I'd run in production

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: For small group sizes, this query outperforms yours, according to my benchmarks which I've edited into the question. So asymptotic complexity isn't everything here, it very much depends on the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Many RDBMS have constructs that are particularly suited to this problem.  MySQL ***isn't*** one of them.

This leads you to three basic approaches.

- Check each record to see if it is one you want, using EXISTS and a correlated sub-query in an EXISTS clause.  *(@acatt's answer, but I understand that MySQL doesn't always optimise this very well.  Ensure that you have a composite index on `(g,a,b)` before assuming that MySQL won't do this very well.)*
- Do a half cartesian product to full-fill the same check.  Any record which does not join is a target record.  Where each group ('g') is large, this can quickly degrade performance *(If there are 10 records for each unique value of `g`, this will yield ~50 records and discard 49.  For a group size of 100 it yields ~5000 records and discard 4999)*, but it **is** great for small group sizes. *(@xdazz's answer.)*
- Or use multiple sub-queries to determine the MAX(a) and then the MAX(b)...

Multiple sequential sub-queries...

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM
  (SELECT g,    MAX(a) AS a FROM yourTable GROUP BY g   ) AS searchA
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT g, a, MAX(b) AS b FROM yourTable GROUP BY g, a) AS searchB
    ON  searchA.g = searchB.g
    AND searchA.a = searchB.a
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  yourTable.g = searchB.g
    AND yourTable.a = searchB.a
    AND yourTable.b = searchB.b
```

Depending on how MySQL optimises the second sub-query, this may or may not be more performant than the other options.  It is, however, the longest *(and potentially least maintainable)* code for the given task.

Assuming an composite index on all three search fields `(g, a, b)`, I would presume it to be best for large group sizes of `g`.  But that should be tested.

For small group sizes of `g`, I'd go with @xdazz's answer.

**EDIT**

There is also a brute force approach.

- Create an identical table, but with an AUTO_INCREMENT column as an id.
- Insert your table into this clone, ordered by g, a, b.
- The id's can then be found with `SELECT g, MAX(id)`.
- This result can then be used to look-up the `v` values you need.

This is unlikely to be the best approach.  If it is, it is effectively a condmenation of MySQL's optimiser's ability to deal with this type of problem.

That said, every engine has it's weak spots.  So, personally, I try everything until I *think* I understand how the RDBMS is behaving and can make my choice :)

**EDIT**

Example using `ROW_NUMBER()`.  *(Oracle, SQL Server, PostGreSQL, etc)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

Comment: It's not really part of my original question, but I'd welcome a few examples of what constructs other RDBMS provide. Perhaps a parenthesis naming a few, with links where available.

Comment: @MvG - `ROW_NUMBER()` answer added.  This is an analytic function, or window function, that some RDBMS have implemented.  It is part of the ever evolving SQL standard.  The standard defines language constructs, not how to implement them - this means that the different RDBMS have different sub-sets of that standard ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using a correlated query:

```
SELECT g, v
FROM tab t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tab
    WHERE g = t.g
        AND a > t.a
        OR (a = t.a AND b > t.b)
    )
```

Comment: According to the [execution plan](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad3987/35) this `NOT EXISTS` thing is still a DEPENDENT SUBQUERY: it will be executed repeatedly, once for each row in the table.

Comment: @MvG I was under the impression that there were performance issues related to dependent sub-queries but this was resolved at some point.  Apologies if this isn't the case. Moreover, xdazz's solution appears to be the best here.

Comment: @acatt - I would suggest that there may be a tipping point.  The half-cartesian-product version may scale much worse than this answer.  As the size of the groups grows this may become relatively more effective, and may at some point become better.

Comment: I was under the same impression, which is why I wanted to avoid them. If issues were resolved, I wonder whether the version in my question benefits from that optimization as well. @Dems, thanks for pointing this out. Will make accepting a *single* answer a lot harder, though.

Comment: @MvG : Accept either the most informative answer to you, or the answer that contains the approach you actually use. And upvote all the others. *(Then post a cheque for £10 to me at my home address of **BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP**)*