# MySQL - return rows in one table that correspond to minimum date in another (indirectly linked) table

Tags: mysql, join, min, multi-table

Table semesters:

```
semesterID  startDate
1           2013-01-01
2           2013-03-01
3           2013-06-01
```

Table classes:

```
classID  class_title  semesterID
1        Math         1
2        Science      1
3        Math         2
4        Science      2
5        Math         3
6        Science      3
```

Table persons:

```
personID  firstName  lastName
1         John       Jones
2         Steve      Smith
```

Table class_person:

```
classID  personID
1        1
2        1
5        1
6        1
3        2
4        2
5        2
6        2
```

**I need to get a list of all the people, with the first semester in which they took a class (semester with the oldest startDate).**

```
firstName,  lastName, semesterID, startDate
John        Jones     1           2013-01-01
Steve       Smith     2           2013-03-01
```

I've spent hours trying to figure this out.  Here's the closest I've gotten (although it is not close at all!):

```
SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName, MIN(s.startDate) AS min_startDate
FROM semesters s
INNER JOIN classes c ON s.semesterID = c.semesterID
INNER JOIN class_person cp ON cp.classID = c.classID
INNER JOIN persons p ON p.personID = cp.personID
GROUP BY cs.personID
ORDER BY min_startDate, p.lastName, p.firstName
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could end up using a monster like the following ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a399e/5)):

```
select persons.firstName, persons.lastName,
       semesters.semesterID, semesters.startDate
from persons, semesters,
(select p.personID,
 (select semesters.semesterID
  from semesters, classes, class_person
  where semesters.semesterID = classes.semesterID
    and classes.classID = class_person.classID
    and class_person.personID = p.personID
  order by semesters.startDate
  limit 1) as semesterID
 from (select distinct personID from class_person) as p
) as ps
where persons.personID = ps.personID
  and semesters.semesterID = ps.semesterID
```

The subquery `p` identifies all persons. For each, `ps` will contain a single row. Its `personID` is simply copied, its `semesterID` is computed by a subquery, which sorts semesters by date but returns the ID. The outermost query then re-adds the date.

If you don't really need the `semesterID`, you could avoid one layer. If your semesters are in order, i.e. their IDs have the same order as their startDates, then you could simply use a single query, much like your own, and return `min(semesterID)` and `min(startDate)`.

On the whole, this question reminds me a lot of my own question, [Select one value from a group based on order from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12726549/1468366). Answers suggested there will likely apply here as well. In particular, there are approaches using user variables which I still don't feel comfortable about, but which will make this whole mess *a lot* easier and seem to work well enough. So adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728212/1468366), you get a query like this ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a399e/11)):

```
SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName, s2.semesterID, s2.startDate
FROM persons p
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT @rowNum:=IF(@personID=cp.personID,@rowNum+1,1) rowNum,
        @personId:=cp.personID personID,
        s.semesterID, s.startDate
 FROM (SELECT @personID:=NULL,@rowNum:=0) dummy
 INNER JOIN semesters s
 INNER JOIN classes c ON s.semesterID = c.semesterID
 INNER JOIN class_person cp ON cp.classID = c.classID
 ORDER BY cp.personID, s.startDate
) s2 ON p.personID = s2.personID
WHERE s2.rowNum = 1
```

I'll leave adapting the other answers as an excercise.

Comment: Thanks so much MvG, your first solution worked perfectly.  (The second one did not!)