# Ties on Hall of Fame (group player, max level then max score for each game when month is...)

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

Need to list a Hall of Fame of best players, the database contains each single game player in different games.

**The level has the priority, if the level are the same, check the highest score.**

I've a database with user_id, level, score, game and data. Schema here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (`user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`level` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,`game` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`score` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`data` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`user_id`, `level`, `game`, `score`,`data`) VALUES
  ('1', '7', 'pacman', '8452','2018-02-14 15:00:00'),
  ('1', '9', 'pacman', '9999','2018-02-10 16:30:00'),
  ('2', '8', 'pacman', '8500','2018-02-24 17:30:00'),
  ('1', '10', 'pacman', '9100','2018-02-15 18:30:00'),
  ('1', '10', 'pacman', '8800','2018-02-15 18:11:00'),
  ('1', '11', 'snake', '9600','2018-02-14 15:00:00'),
  ('1', '6', 'snake', '7020','2018-02-11 11:30:00'),
  ('2', '8', 'snake', '8500','2018-02-24 14:00:00'),
  ('2', '12', 'snake', '9200','2018-02-25 19:00:00'),
  ('2', '12', 'snake', '9800','2018-02-25 19:20:00'),
  ('1', '4', 'pacman', '2452','2018-03-11 15:00:00'),
  ('1', '6', 'pacman', '4999','2018-03-07 16:30:00'),
  ('2', '7', 'pacman', '5500','2018-03-02 17:30:00'),
  ('1', '7', 'pacman', '5100','2018-03-01 18:30:00'),
  ('1', '3', 'snake', '3600','2018-03-03 15:00:00'),
  ('1', '5', 'snake', '4220','2018-03-01 11:30:00'),
  ('2', '5', 'snake', '3900','2018-03-04 14:00:00'),
  ('2', '5', 'snake', '5200','2018-03-05 19:00:00');
```

i want retrieve the hall of fame for selected month and game,
for example if i choose **pacman** on **march** the result should be:

```
user level score
2     7    5500
1     7    5100
```

i tryed this how suggest in other similar topic

```
select d1.*
from docs d1 
left outer join docs d2
on (d1.user_id = d2.user_id and d1.level < d2.level)
where d2.user_id is null
order by level desc;
```

but i've duplicate levels for same user, then i cant choose the game or the month.

here there is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3d1e6/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a long work, study and research this is the best solution for me:

```
SELECT user_id, level, score, game
  FROM (
            SELECT *, 
                   @rn := IF(user_id = @g, @rn + 1, 1) rn, 
                   @g := user_id
              FROM (select @g := null, @rn := 0) x, 
                   docs where game='pacman'
          ORDER BY user_id, level desc, score desc, game
       ) X
 WHERE rn = 1 order by level desc, score desc;
```

the explanation is in this topic [Select one value from a group based on order from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726549/select-one-value-from-a-group-based-on-order-from-other-columns)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT x.* FROM docs x
JOIN 
(select user_id
      , game
      , MONTH(data) month
      , MAX(score) score
   from docs 
  where game = 'pacman' 
    and MONTH(data) = 3 
  group 
     by user_id
      , game
      , MONTH(data)
 ) y
 ON y.user_id = x.user_id
 AND y.game = x.game
 AND y.month = MONTH(x.data)
 AND y.score = x.score;
```

or something like that